# Why does my Listbox print the whole list in one line?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox, opc-ua

I create a list by appending dictionary entries containing display_name, browse_name  and node_id of `OPCUA` server nodes. When I print the list, all the elements are on one line. I have no idea why. Please help!

```
# Code for inserting elements into the Listbox

def display_nodes(self, nodes_list):
        # Code zum Anzeigen der Nodes im GUI
        i = 0
        print(nodes_list,sep=" ")
        display_text=""
        self.nodes_listbox.delete(0,tk.END)
        for node in nodes_list:
            display_text=str(node)
            self.nodes_listbox.insert(tk.END,display_text)
    pass

# Code for reading nodes and adding them to the List

    def read_nodes(self,node):
        # Code zum Lesen der Nodes vom Server 
        

        for childId in node.get_children():
            ch = self.client.get_node(childId)
            print(ch.get_node_class())
          
            if ch.get_node_class() == ua.NodeClass.Variable:
                #if str(ch.get_browse_name()).find("QualifiedName(1:") != -1:
                if (str(ch.nodeid)).find("ns=1")!= -1:
                    node_data={
                        'display_name':ch.get_display_name(),
                        'browse_name':ch.get_browse_name(),
                        'node_id':str(ch.nodeid),
                    }
                    print(node_data)
                    self.nodes_list.append(node_data)               

            else:
                #if str(ch.get_browse_name).find("QualifiedName(1:") != -1:
                    node_data={
                        'display_name':ch.get_display_name(),
                        'browse_name':ch.get_browse_name(),
                        'node_id':str(ch.nodeid),
                        #"data_type":ch.get_data_type_as_variant_type(),

                    }
                    
                    print(node_data)
                    self.read_nodes(ch)
                   
        return[self.nodes_list]
```

Comment: Does this help? `self.nodes_listbox.insert(tk.END, *display_text)`

Comment: Yess! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i print the list, all the elements are in one line.

The problem can be fixed by using asterik(*)

Change this:

```
self.nodes_listbox.insert(tk.END,display_text)
```

to:

```
self.nodes_listbox.insert(tk.END, *display_text)
```